# How to get path to class file in eclipse and linux in java?

Tags: java, linux, eclipse

In eclipse for windows, when I run

```
public class HelloWorld { 
   public static void main(String[] args) { 
      System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
   }
}
```

It gives me the path of the project root folder (which contains the bin folder which has the class file). For example

`SampleProject`

and the class file is actually located at

`SampleProject\bin\myclass.class`

But if I run the same program in linux with

```
javac myclass.java
java myclass
```

it gives me the directory that has the .class file, which is the same as `pwd` command. This is what I want in eclipse for windows. I want some code that will give me the path to the class file in both eclipse for windows and linux.

Does anyone know how do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you'd like a method that retrieves a class' path on disk. This is easily achievable, like so:

```
public String getClassPath(Class c) {
    try {
        return c.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI().getPath();
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

**NOTE** this will work even if the class is contained in a jar file. It will return the path to the jar in this case.

Comment: Use another name for your parameter, `class` will not compile.

Comment: @Mathias, I always forget `class` is a special keyword. I usually do lower case object name. Thanks, good catch!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to do this:

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(HelloWorld.class.getResource("HelloWorld.class"));
    }
}
```